# Ansible: supplying input file to command

Tags: ansible

In my Ansible playbook, I need to run a `command` that takes as an argument the path to an XML file. The command will read this XML file.

My questions is: how is this file supplied to `command` as input. As far as I have understood, the command is run on the remote machine. Do I need to, for example, use `copy` to first transfer the input file to the remote host (say, to `/tmp/`)? Or is there a more straightforward builtin way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Copy the file and then execute your command.